# How do I route to a method in ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api), if I have this in my WebApiConfig.cs:

```cs
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "ActionApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
```

I should be able to route to a method in my API controller using a URL like this:

http://localhost:55601/api/Customers/Search

Here is my method:

```cs
[ResponseType(typeof(int))]
        [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Search([FromBody]CustomerDTO SearchTerm)
        {
            string Name = SearchTerm.Name;
            string Email = SearchTerm.Email;
            string PhoneNumber = SearchTerm.Phone;

            var customer = db.Customers.Single(c => c.Name == Name && c.EmailAddress == Email && c.PhoneNumber == PhoneNumber);
            return Ok(customer.id);
        }
```

I'm sending the search data as a JSON object (using HTTP POST method) in the request body.

However, I get an error saying:

> Multiple actions were found that match the request

I only have one method in this controller called Search.

I would have thought this should be pretty straightforward, and work the same way it does with MVC controllers. But I think I'm missing something obvious. Can anyone tell me what it is?

---

EDIT: As per @KevinLaw's request, adding code for controller showing upblic methods. Also, for further information the following request (HTTP GET) works as expected:

http://localhost:55601/api/Customers?email=[recipient@domain]

```cs
public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: api/Customers
    public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        //...
    }

    // GET: api/Customers/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomer(int id)
    {
        //...
    }

    // GET: api/Customers/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCustomerByEmail(string email)
    {
        //...
    }

    // PUT: api/Customers/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public IHttpActionResult PutCustomer(int id, Customer customer)
    {
        //...
    }

    // POST: api/Customers
    [ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
    public IHttpActionResult PostCustomer(Customer customer)
    {
        //...
    }

    [ResponseType(typeof(int))]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult SearchCustomer([FromBody]CustomerDTO SearchTerm)
    {
        //...
    }

    // DELETE: api/Customers/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(Customer))]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteCustomer(int id)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please show us other methods  and controller class name of this controller?

Comment: @KevinLaw do you want me to post the full code for the controller? The controller class name is CustomersController

Comment: I just want to make sure that you route comes with right controller. It would be nice if you could post full code(Public methods would be enough)

Comment: Understood, updating now.

Comment: In case there is a typo, the full code you pasted is a bit different from code snippet you pasted before. In the full code case, You should use http://localhost:55601/api/Customers/SearchCustomer to reach your route.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, actually I tried that too, same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `WebApiController` uses the REST API specs.

Which state that in a Web Api Controller there can be Zero - One Http Verb.

What i mean by that is that you can have one `GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH`

The reason you don't have any problem with the GET is because you have them correctly overloaded. () (int) (string).

But your Posts is (Customer) (CustomerDTO) They are both complex objects and the Binder cannot identify which is which when binding to the complex object.

For this to work you need to use Route Attributes or explicit route.

- [Attribute Routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)
- [Explicit Routing pt1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)
- [Explicit Routing pt2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection)

I think the links are enough to get you started.
If you still want to see some code on your specific case leave a comment below and i will give you some examples.

Thanks

**EDIT:** Added Examples

### Attribute Routing

On *WebApiConfig.cs*

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
```

On Controller

```
[RoutePrefix("api/test")]
public class TestingController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("search")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]SearchCriteria criteria)
    {
        return Ok(criteria);
    }
}

public class SearchCriteria
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

### Explicit Routing

On *WebApiConfig.cs*

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "SearchTest",
            routeTemplate: "api/test/search",
            defaults: new { controller = "Testing", action = "Search" }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "TestingController",
            routeTemplate: "api/test/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Testing", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

On Controller

```
public class TestingController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Search([FromBody]SearchCriteria criteria)
    {
        return Ok(criteria);
    }
}

public class SearchCriteria
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. Looks like this is a symptom of leanring by example rather than by principle. Clearly I don't understand the fundamentals of how this technology works properly.

Comment: @MattG Check my edit :) If you need any further assistance feel free to ask

Comment: Thanks again Nick. I still can't get this working, I get the same result. for now I'mm actually building a Search controller as I need to get this over the line.